# Using jquery-validate.How to change the timing of trigger validating of only one element with other elements stay default

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm writing a page for registering and using jquery-validate for validation.
A simple example of my problem is as follow.

### JS CODE

```
$("#registerForm").validate({
    rules : {
        "loginname" : {
            required : true,
            minlength : 6,
            maxlength : 20
        },
        "phoneMessage" : {
            remote : {
                url : "phoneMessageValidate.do",
                type : "post",
                dataType : "json",
                data : {
                    phoneMessage : function() {
                        return $("#phoneMessage").val();
                    }
                },
            },
        },
    },
    submitHandler : function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
})         //edition:jquery-1.11.3   jquery-validation-1.14.0
<form id="registerForm">
    <input type="text" id="loginname" name="loginname"></input>
    <input type="text" id="phoneMessage" name="phoneMessage"></input>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"></input>
</form>
```

By default, **all the elements will be validated when the focus is out.** It is useful, but in this case, **my requirement is:**

1. The phoneMessage is validated **only when the form is submitted**, while
   other element stay default setting.
2. The invalid status of any elements can block the submit of form.

By searching the introduce site of jquery-validate:

http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#onfocusout

I found that we can change the timing to trigger validating by setting the parameter "onfocusout = false" in validate function. **As the two element is defined in the same validate function, how can I change the validation of one of them?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. The `phoneMessage` is validated only when the form is submitted, while other element stay default setting.

Simply override the `onfocusout` function with a conditional function.

```
onfocusout: function(element) {
    if (element.name === "phoneMessage") {
        // Disable `onfocusout` for 'phoneMessage' element
        return false;
    } else { 
        // DEFAULT `onfocusout` function
        if ( !this.checkable(element) && (element.name in this.submitted || !this.optional(element))) {
            this.element(element);
        }
    }
}
```

**DEMO:  https://jsfiddle.net/z73efhjz/**

> 2. The invalid status of any elements can block the submit of form.

That's already the default behavior of the plugin.

FYI- The `<input>` tag is not a container element so there is no such thing as a `</input>` tag.

Comment: That's what I need, you answer is accurate and detailed, thank you.